# Angular Material Theming - Treshold for black/white decision

Tags: angular, colors, angular-material, theming, angular-material-theming

Is there a way to set the treshold in Angular Material's theming, when white and when black text is used e.g. in buttons but also in other controls?

In my case, there is black text automatically used, where white text would be better:

[image]  [image]